# Where to save the core data context...?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have gone through a couple of similar questions but could reach a definite point about this...

I think saving the context in `applicationWillTerminate`: should be enough but will making too many changes on the core data scratch pad increase the memory of my application...?

And should I save it more often..? I am aware that saving the context over and over again decrease the life of flash drive of the device and apple recommends that we should do it less often.

Are there any other scenarios where the application forgets the core data context appart from where it gets terminated...?

Thanks for your inputs..

Comment: Depends on how angry your customers will be when they lose all their data because of a crash or some unexpected circumstance I guess.  You will not receive a termination message when your app is suspended either.  So if it is killed in that state poof goes all the data.  Unless your application doesn't support background mode, terminate will rarely be called.

Comment: so I should save my context in applicationWillEnterBackground as well, thanks for that input.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887437/objective-c-core-data-saving-approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The saving behavior of your application depends... on the application. I mean, in a document based app, the user expects the document to be saved when he hits cmd-S. And so you should do.  More and more users expect the applications they use to autosave.

The saving behavior is a design choice, from the user standpoint. User interface and interactions design decides how the application is supposed to behave.

Besides these considerations, technical realities can't be ignored of course. Memory usage, crashing bugs and data losses, undo management, battery drain, all of this have an impact on the application behavior and on the user in the end. I really don't think SSD life expectancy is a factor you should consider tho.

Last word : you can have more than one object context for a given store. You can have child contextes. So you can save parts of the data instead of the full change backlog, you can prioritize some entities over others... Many implementation choices and possible strategies, but they should be driven by the user interface and interactions design. They have to.

Save when it makes sense for the user.

Answer (score -1):

this is one kind of way to store data in to Coredata.

```
-(void) setEmailContactsToCoredata:(id)sender  
{    

        NSManagedObjectContext *context=[appDelegate managedObjectContext];

        NSManagedObject *newData = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EmailContacts" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        [newData setValue:self.emailTextField.text forKey:@"email_ID"];



        NSError *error;

       if (![context save:&error])
       {
            NSLog(@"There was an error while inserting Data into coredata");
       }
       else
       {
           NSLog(@"Success fully Saved your email id");  
       }  
}
```

Comment: You didn't understand my question.. I know how to save the data... please read it carefully.. saving it like you do for every single time  a new email is added damages the hard drive of the device.